# Laravel / Eloquent - How to use conlumn value as parameter inside whereHas

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, eloquent, laravel-query-builder

I'm querying with eloquent between two connection in different servers and I want to filter the related table using a column value from the main object.

The expected results are orders which have the column "status_mkt" on table "orders" at server "A", different from the column "status" on table "orderERP" at server "B".

I've tried something like this, but without success:

```
Order::with('orderERP', 'store', 'store.marketplace')
                         ->where('status_mkt', '<>', 'DELIVERED')
                         ->whereHas('orderERP', function ($query) {
                             $query->where('status', '<>', 'orders.status_mkt');// this doesn't work
                         })
                         ->get();
```